# I am getting this error "Keyword not supported: '(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;database'."

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "(LocalDb)\\MSSQLLocalDb;Database=BooklistRazor;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True"
  },
```

This is my connection string for an ASP.NET Core core project. I am a beginner in ASP.NET Core. I am trying to make a project while learning but getting this error:

> Keyword not supported: '(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;database'.

Comment: You need a `server=` or `data source=` before your server name - try this: `"DefaultConnection": "Server=(LocalDb)\\MSSQLLocalDb;Database=BooklistRazor;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True"`

Comment: Thanks a lot Brother really appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

Your connection string should be like below.

```
"DefaultConnection": "Data Source=<ServerName>;Initial Catalog=<DbName>;User ID=<UserId>;Password=fx4me-"
```