# When typing "update-Database" from Package Manager Console, "The ConnectionString property has not been initialized." his mistake

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core-webapi

while learning ASP.net core api from Visual Studio, I write the following from Package Manager Console to update the database: `update-Database`.

I get the following error after typing:

```
PM> Update-Database
Build started...
Build succeeded.
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Model.Validation[30000]
      No store type was specified for the decimal property 'Price' on entity type 'Book'. This will cause values to be silently truncated if they do not fit in the default precision and scale. Explicitly specify the SQL server column type that can accommodate all the values in 'OnModelCreating' using 'HasColumnType', specify precision and scale using 'HasPrecision', or configure a value converter using 'HasConversion'.
System.InvalidOperationException: The ConnectionString property has not been initialized.
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.PermissionDemand()
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.PermissionDemand(DbConnection outerConnection)
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, SqlConnectionOverrides overrides)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open(SqlConnectionOverrides overrides)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerConnection.OpenDbConnection(Boolean errorsExpected)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenInternal(Boolean errorsExpected)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.Open(Boolean errorsExpected)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerDatabaseCreator.<>c__DisplayClass18_0.<Exists>b__0(DateTime giveUp)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ExecutionStrategyExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass12_0`2.<Execute>b__0(DbContext _, TState s)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.Execute[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`3 operation, Func`3 verifySucceeded)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ExecutionStrategyExtensions.Execute[TState,TResult](IExecutionStrategy strategy, TState state, Func`2 operation, Func`2 verifySucceeded)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerDatabaseCreator.Exists(Boolean retryOnNotExists)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerDatabaseCreator.Exists()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.HistoryRepository.Exists()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.Migrate(String targetMigration)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.UpdateDatabase(String targetMigration, String connectionString, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabaseImpl(String targetMigration, String connectionString, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabase.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
The ConnectionString property has not been initialized.
```

Book.cs code:

```
namespace WebApi.Models
{
    public class Book
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
    }
}
```

appsettings.json code:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"

    }
  },

  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "sqlConnection": "(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB; Initial Catalog = bsStoreApp; Intregrated Security=true;"
  }
}
```

20230804083855_startPoint.cs code:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations;

#nullable disable

namespace WebApi.Migrations
{
    /// <inheritdoc />
    public partial class startPoint : Migration
    {
        /// <inheritdoc />
        protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "Books",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    Id = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false)
                        .Annotation("SqlServer:Identity", "1, 1"),
                    Title = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: false),
                    Price = table.Column<decimal>(type: "decimal(18,2)", nullable: false)
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_Books", x => x.Id);
                });
        }

        /// <inheritdoc />
        protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            migrationBuilder.DropTable(
                name: "Books");
        }
    }
}
```

what is the error in my code and you can tell me if there is something I can add.
asp.net core version:6.0.

Comment: Have you set the web app project as start up one in the VS?

Comment: @GuruStron, Yes, I did what you said.

Comment: Please provide a [mre], command you run and screenshot of package manager console (including dropdowns) and solution tree

Comment: @GuruStron everything in my project is in it:(https://drive.google.com/file/d/1elf8bufyKutVa_FEuVVU0MFe-y6A1Aat/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to fix the connection string configuration `sqlConnections` -> `sqlConnection`, name of the connection string should match one in the configuration :

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<RepositoryContext>(opts =>
    opts.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("sqlConnection"))
);
```

For the future - you can always introduce a variable and check if it is null (for example in the debugger or via explicit check):

```
var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("sqlConnection");
if(connectionString is null) throw new Exception("Incorrect string");
builder.Services.AddDbContext<RepositoryContext>(opts =>
    opts.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
```

Comment: I wrote program.cs as you above but I got the following error: "Keyword not supported: '(localdb)\mssqllocaldb; initial catalog'. " error log: (https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bzNf5AEfL7264uZlswJG6DBAjM0qkPJK/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: @nurinn it means that you have an error in your connection string. I don't have localdb installed so I would argue that is another question. Check out [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63090664/2501279)

Comment: Thank you. I had to write the following in the "sqlConnection" section of the appsettings.json code: "Data Source = (localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB; Initial Catalog = bsStoreApp; Integrated Security = true;". worked this time.